# How to make an efficient operator+=

Tags: dart

It looks as if *operator+=* is not something that can be user defined (from Dart Language Specification):

> The following names are allowed for user-defined operators: <, >, <=, >=, ==, -, +, /,  ̃/, *, %, |, ˆ, &, <<, >>, []=, [],  ̃.

However, if you provide an *operator+(...)* then that is used when operator+= is called.

The question I have is, how do you effect an efficient *operator+=()* without requiring the creation of a new instance?

```dart
class DividendBreakdown {

  DividendBreakdown(this.qualified, this.unqualified, this.capitalGainDistribution);

  bool operator==(DividendBreakdown other) =>
    identical(this, other) ||
    qualified == other.qualified &&
    unqualified == other.unqualified &&
    capitalGainDistribution == other.capitalGainDistribution;

  num qualified = 0.0;
  num unqualified = 0.0;
  num capitalGainDistribution = 0.0;

  DividendBreakdown.empty();

  DividendBreakdown operator +(DividendBreakdown other) {
    return new DividendBreakdown(qualified + other.qualified,
        unqualified + other.unqualified,
        capitalGainDistribution + other.capitalGainDistribution);
  }
}
```

Comment: you mean where `a+b != a`, but `a+=b == a`?

Comment: Yes. identical(a+b,a) == false, but identical(a+=b,a) == true, the latter avoiding a new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, unless you also alter the behaviour of the + operator. The += operator and other compound assignment operators are simply shorthand for a normal operator and then an immediate assignment.

There is no way to extract extra information in the + operator to determine whether an assignment will be performed immediately or not, and therefore you must always return a new instance in case assignment is not being performed.

Instead, use your own method:

```dart
DividendBreakdown add(DividendBreakdown other) {
  //...
}
```

Comment: Ok. So, maybe leave _operator+_ as expected but get an efficient _operator+=_ with new method: _void plusEqual(DividendBreakdown other)_

That way both _operator+_ and _operator+=_ work as expected, it is just that _operator+=_ is unnecessarily expensive and plusEqual can be an efficient replacement.

Comment: Yup, that is definitely a good idea. Similar to how we use normal String concatenation for convenience but StringBuffers when we need the performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve efficiency problem from the another perspective. For example, if you have two huge complex collections and + operator will combine them into to the new one, it could be slow. But instead of directly combine  those collections  and creating new one, you can implement special collection view that will represent combination of them and perform heavy tasks 'on-demand' in a lazy style.

Answer (score -1):

You can return this (or other) if you'd like to:

```
class Point {
  int x;
  int y;
  Point(this.x, this.y);
  Point operator +(Point other){
    this.x = x + other.x;
    this.y = y + other.y;
    return this;
  }
  String toString(){
    return "Point: x: $x, y: $y";
  }
}
```

And usage:

```
Point p1 = new Point(1,1);
Point p2 = new Point(2,2);
print((p1+p2));
```

Result with: Point: x: 3, y: 3

Comment: I doubt anyone will want the side effect of redefining the caller. In your example p1 is now x: 3, y:3 simply because of a print statement!

Comment: The question was about using a "+" operator without creating new instance and I believe it's still an answer. You can do `p1 = p1+p2;` and have the same result - p1 will change (either way). You can also call `p1+p2;` only and it still will be working (besides semantic).

Comment: The question is about the += operator, not the + operator. However the += operator calls the + operator. Your solution works but violates what anyone would expect from using a + operator.

Comment: Yes - I need operator+ to still work as expected (i.e. non-modifying)